# Equality operator overloading in struct and classes

Tags: c#, .net

If I do the overloading of `operator ==` for a class, I must perform some checks before comparing the fields:

- if both arguments are null, or both arguments are the same instance, then returns true

  Example: `if (System.Object.ReferenceEquals(arg1, arg2)) return true;`
- if one is null, but not both, then returns false

  Example: `if (((object)arg1 == null) || ((object)arg2 == null)) return false;`

Indeed, if I have a struct and I want to do the overloading of `operator ==`, these checks are not necessary, rather they are useless, for the following reasons: a struct is a *value type*, so it can not be null, for example `DateTime date = null;` is not valid, because `DateTime` (that is a struct) is not a reference type, so you can not compare two `DateTime`, one of which is set to `null`.

I created a simple struct `Point2D` with `operator ==`, then I compare an instance of `Point2D` with `null`:

```
Point2D point = new Point2D(0,0);
Console.WriteLine((point == null));
```

1. Obviously the `operator ==` it is not called, but the comparison returns `False`. Which method is called?
2. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) states that overloading this operator in not-immutable types is not recommended. Why?

Comment: You should try to ask only one question at a time. If you have two questions, ask them separately.

Comment: @svick: Sorry. For the next questions I will avoid this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it seems that the compiler optimizes this away.  I tried this code:

```
System.Drawing.Point point = new System.Drawing.Point(0,0);
Console.WriteLine((point == null));
```

And it generated the following IL:

```
IL_0000:  ldloca.s    00 
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0004:  call        System.Drawing.Point..ctor
IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_000A:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

This ultimately boils down to "Create a Point, and then write false to the command line"

This also explains why it doesn't call your operator.  A struct can never be null, and in circumstances where the compiler can guarantee that you are always going to get false as a result, it doesn't bother issuing code to call an operator at all.

The same thing happens with this code, even though String is a class and overload the == operator:

```
System.Drawing.Point point = new System.Drawing.Point(0,0);
Console.WriteLine("foo" == null);
```

As for immutability...  The == operator in C# is generally interpreted to mean "reference equality", e.g. these two variables point to the same instance of the class.  If you are overloading it, then you generally mean to say that two instances of the class, while *not the same instance*, should behave as if they were the same instance when their data is the same.  The classic example is Strings.  `"A" == GiveMeAnA()` even though the actual String reference returned by `GiveMeAnA` may not be the same as the one represented by the literal `"A"`.

If you overloaded the `==` operator on classes which were not immutable, then mutation of a class after `==` had been evaluated could cause numerous subtle bugs.

Comment: I use LINQPad ( http://linqpad.net ) or Reflector ( http://reflector.net ). The former shows you the IL of arbitrary snippets of code, the latter decompiles assemblies into IL and can re-generate equivalent C# from that IL. There is also a built-in tool called ILDASM ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.80).aspx ) Understanding IL is a tricky thing- see http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/02/07/getting-started-understanding-msil-assembly-language/

Answer (score 17):

Chris Shain's answer is *correct* but does not explain *why this is legal*.

When you override the equality operator, and both the operands are *non-nullable value types*, and the the return type is *bool*, then for free we give you a *lifted* operator. That is, if you have

```
public static bool operator ==(S s1, S s2) { ... }
```

then *for no additional cost* you get

```
public static bool operator ==(S? s1, S? s2) { ... }
```

It is *that* operator that is being called. Of course the compiler knows that the result will always be false because one of the operands is null and the other never is.

There used to be a warning to the effect that your code always returns false but we accidentally disabled it a couple versions back and never actually turned it back on.  I'm working on this very code tomorrow in the Roslyn compiler so I'll see what I can do to get it back in shape.

Comment: Reading your answers is always educational, even after writing .NET code for nearly a decade.  Thanks :-)

Comment: Eric, you're saying that here we have two operands of type `Point` and `null`; there is no implicit conversion between them, but the compiler calls the operator for another type, to which both operands can be implicitly converted.  That seems inconsistent with the treatment of the conditional operator, where you cannot say `int? x = someBool ? 7 : null;`  I started with version 2 of C#; would an expression like `1 == null` have failed to compile in earlier versions?

Comment: @phoog: That's not quite the right analogy to make. The right analogy to make for *operator overload resolution* is *method overload resolution*. If you have a static method `int? Operators.Add(int?, int?)` and you call `Operator.Add(1, null)` then you'd expect that method to be chosen, even though int is not convertible to null and null is not convertible to int, right? Think of all the built-in and lifted operators as being static methods on a class Operators; operator overload resolution simply does overload resolution on those methods.

Comment: So just to be crystal clear, does that mean that for a non-nullable struct with an overloaded operator== the auto-generated lifted operator performs the null checking before calling the overloaded operator==, which is why the overloaded operator== never needs to perform this check itself?

Comment: @Neutrino: Correct. The semantics of the autogenerated lifted operator are to check for nullity first, and only if both operands are known to be non-null is the unlifted operator invoked.

Comment: This is the information I needed. I was struggling a bit with how to approach the requirement of a bit-packed struct that has nullability built in. Now I see i need to manually write the lifted `==(S? left, S? right)` operator to solve it.